# three js Collision detection in group (THREE.Group)

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, game-engine, game-physics

I am working on 3D AABB collisions detection for box and sphere.

If box is directly added to scene then collision is detected but if its added in a group (THREE.Group) and rotated, then collision is not detected.

This is the code to add box

```
function addPlatforms() {

    var coreGroup = new THREE.Group(); // this is the group
    scene.add(coreGroup);

    var box = [];

    cube_box1 = new THREE.Box3(new THREE.Vector3(), new THREE.Vector3());
    box.push(new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 0.2), materials.solid));
    box[0].position.set(-1.83, -0.22, 1.11);
    box[0].rotation.x += Math.PI / 2;
    box[0].rotation.z -= 0.78;
    box[0].receiveShadow = true;


    cube_box2 = new THREE.Box3(new THREE.Vector3(), new THREE.Vector3());
    box.push(new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 0.2), materials.solid));
    box[1].position.set(-2.15, -0.22, 0.51);
    box[1].rotation.x += Math.PI / 2;
    box[1].receiveShadow = true;

    var platGroup = new THREE.Group();
    platGroup.add(box[0]);
    platGroup.add(box[1]);
    platGroup.rotation.y -= 2;
    platGroup.position.y  = 1;

    coreGroup.add(platGroup);


    cube_box1.setFromObject(box[0]);
    platformArr.push(cube_box1);

    cube_box2.setFromObject(box[1]);
    platformArr.push(cube_box2);
}
```

Code to get Collision between box and sphere.

Visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/3D_collision_detection/Bounding_volume_collision_detection_with_THREE.js

```
THREE.Sphere.__closest = new THREE.Vector3();
THREE.Sphere.prototype.intersectsBox = function(box) {
    // get box closest point to sphere center by clamping
    THREE.Sphere.__closest.set(this.center.x, this.center.y, this.center.z);
    THREE.Sphere.__closest.clamp(box.min, box.max);

    var distance = this.center.distanceToSquared(THREE.Sphere.__closest);
    return distance < (this.radius * this.radius);
};

function isCollision() {
    for (var i = 0; i < platformArr.length; i++) {
        _cubeBox = platformArr[i];
        return sphereBox.intersectsBox(_cubeBox);
    }
}
```

This is how sphere is added

```
function addBall(){

    sphere = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.19, 20, 20), materials.solid);
    sphere.position.set(0, 1, -2);
    sphere.geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
    scene.add(sphere);

    sphereBox = new THREE.Sphere(sphere.position, sphere.geometry.boundingSphere.radius);
    sphereBox.radius = sphere.geometry.boundingSphere.radius;

    cy = sphere.position.y;
}
```

Logic to render

```
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    if (collision) { // ball is on surface
        vy = -vy;
        collision = false;
    }

    cy -= vy * dt;

    sphere.position.y = cy;

    if (vy <= mvy)
        vy += gravity;

    collision = isCollision();
}
```

If a box is added to scene and collision is detected with sphere then its working.
Ex -
Create a simple box and change some properties like rotation and position

```
var _box = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 0.2), materials.solid);
_box.position.set(-1.83, -0.22, 1.11);
_box.rotation.x += Math.PI / 2;
_box.rotation.z -= 0.78;
_box.receiveShadow = true;
```

Then find the collision in animate update

```
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    if (collision) { // ball is on surface
        vy = -vy;
        collision = false;
    }

    cy -= vy * dt;

    sphere.position.y = cy;

    if (vy <= mvy)
        vy += gravity;

    collision = sphereBox.intersectsBox(_box);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, the object's world matrix will be updated every frame. You are instantiating these boxes, transforming, and adding them to the group. Then you instantly call `cube_box1.setFromObject(box[0]);`, which uses `matrixWorld` internally. But the world matrices of the boxes are not set yet. You can wait a frame to let the matrices to be computed automatically, or you have to trigger matrix updates manually:

```
//... your code ...
coreGroup.add(platGroup);

coreGroup.updateMatrixWorld( true );

cube_box1.setFromObject(box[0]);
platformArr.push(cube_box1);
//... your code ...
```

[Three.js Docs Matrix Transformations](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/introduction/Matrix-transformations)

> When either the parent or the child object's transformation changes, you can request that the child object's `matrixWorld` be updated by calling `updateMatrixWorld()`.

[Three.js Docs Object3D](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/Object3D)

> `.matrixAutoUpdate : Boolean`
>
> When this is set, it calculates the matrix of position, (rotation or quaternion) and scale every frame and also recalculates the matrixWorld property. Default is `Object3D.DefaultMatrixAutoUpdate` (true).